# How to split an array in c?

Tags: c, controller, aes

I need a logic to acheive my target. I've buffer array size of 38400. This array data can be filled by a controller. Here i have to obtain an AES algorithm. In that i've to read  16 bytes of data from the buffer then encrypt, upto end of buffer. How to spilt an array into 16 bytes and encrypt? . I used following logic but i can't get it right now ?

```
    unsigned char ptext[16] = "Attack at dawn!";
    unsigned char ctext[16];
    unsigned char decptext[16];
    unsigned char buffer[120*160*2];

    for (int count = 0; count < 120*160*2; count ++)
     buffer[count] = count + 1;

    for (i = 0; i < 120*160*2; i ++)
{

    ptext[i]= buffer[i];

    if(i%15 == 0)
    {
    aes_encrypt(ctx, ptext, ctext);
    for(k = 0; k<=i; k++)
            {
                ptext[k]='\0';
            }
    }
}


 void aes_encrypt(aes_ctx_t *ctx, unsigned char input[16], unsigned char output[16])
 {
    int i;

// copy input to state
for(i = 0; i < 16; i++)
    ctx->state[i & 0x03][i >> 2] = input[i];

aes_addroundkey(ctx, 0);

for(i = 1; i < ctx->rounds; i++) {
    aes_subbytes(ctx);
    aes_shiftrows(ctx);
    aes_mixcolumns(ctx);
    aes_addroundkey(ctx, i);
}

aes_subbytes(ctx);
aes_shiftrows(ctx);
aes_addroundkey(ctx, ctx->rounds);

// copy state to output
for(i = 0; i < 16; i++)
{
    output[i] = ctx->state[i & 0x03][i >> 2];
    printf("%c",output[i]);
}


 }
```

Note: I've filled buffer[] with random numbers.

Me only have to know how to split an array.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Show more of your code. At least the definitions of `ptext`, `ctext`, `ctx`, also the implementation of `aes_encrypt()`.

Comment: If you use some cryptographic features, you should see your buffer as raw bytes and not as ASCII characters like the `'\0'` suggests.
Anyway, make your question clearer. What is your issue ? The AES encryption, the feeding of the AES cipher OR both ?

Comment: Thanks for your replies. I only wants to know how to split the array into 16 bytes . I did implementaion of AES successfully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to "split" the array (whatever "split" means for you.) Just operate on every 16-byte segment of it:

```
void process_segment(unsigned char segment[])
{
    // Work on the first 16 bytes of 'segment'.
}

// ...

unsigned char buffer[120*160*2];

for (size_t i = 0; i < 120*160*2; i += 16) {
    process_segment(buffer + i);
}
```

The above is just an example. If you want a nested `for` loop instead, you'd do something like this:

```
unsigned char buffer[120*160*2];

for (size_t i = 0; i < 120*160*2; i += 16) {
    unsigned char* segment = buffer + i;
    // Work on the first 16 bytes of 'segment'.
    for (size_t j = 0; j < 16; ++j) {
        // Work on segment[j].
    }
}
```

You should probably change your aes_encrypt() function to take an `unsigned char input[]` instead of an `unsigned char input[16]` so that you can pass `segment` to it.

The code you posted would then become something like this:

```
    unsigned char ptext[16] = "Attack at dawn!";
    unsigned char ctext[16];
    unsigned char decptext[16];
    unsigned char buffer[120*160*2];

    for (int count = 0; count < 120*160*2; count++)
        buffer[count] = count + 1;

    for (i = 0; i < 120*160*2; i += 16) {
        unsigned char *segment = buffer + i;
        aes_encrypt(ctx, segment, ctext);
        // Clear the current 16-byte segment.
        memset(segment, '\0', 16);
        // ctext now contains the encrypted data of the current
        // 16-byte segment. I assume you want to save it somewhere
        // now since it will be overridden in the next iteration of
        // the loop.
    }
```

And the signature of your aes_encrypt() function would become:

```
void aes_encrypt(aes_ctx_t *ctx, unsigned char input[],
                 unsigned char output[16])
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. can u please explain the above logic? because i'm getting different size of bytes.

Comment: @chain What do you mean with "getting different size of bytes"?

Comment: For example , i've an array it holds 38400 data. I want to read 0-15 , 16-30, 31-45 .....38384-38400 from that arry. How can i do this?

Comment: @chain In process_segment() you treat `segment` as a 16 byte array. This is just an example. You might as well omit the function and do a nested `for` loop instead.

Comment: @chain OK, I posted some more code on how your original code would look like. Adjust as needed of course.